# Facebook Constantly Switches Between Two Access-Tokens

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm facing a somewhat weird situation. In our application we removed the use of the offline_access-scope and implemented their [new logic to get a new token](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/). Therefore, we use the following URL-template:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=%s
```

We receive the token and its expiration timespan. To avoid conflicts with outdated tokens and minimise the effects on the user, we request a new token frequently. According to the documentation that's actually what Facebook wants us to do and isn't bad practice.

We noticed that Facebook keeps returning two different tokens to us, which influences our screenflow. Using the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) we learned that both tokens are the same except for the `Origin` line:

```
Origin  Unknown
```

compared to

```
Origin  Web
```

As I said all other fields are equal.

The obvious questions are:

1. Why does Facebook do this?
2. How can we influence this to always get the token for `Unknown` or `Web`?
3. Does the difference have any effect on the token or what the user can do?

EDIT:
4. Is it possible that I can't use a token with origin `Web` to perform Open Graph-requests?